# Why does I can't log out even if it works on server-side in Django React

Tags: reactjs, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django and React and I tried to create auth system.
Register and Log In work fine both in server-side and client-side, but the Log out one didn't.

When I send POST method from React it says `POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/logout 403 (Forbidden)` even if it works in Django.

So here's my `UserLogOutView` in Django:

```py
class UserLogOutView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        logout(request)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

And here's the `urls.py`:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('logout', views.UserLogOutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
]
```

So I send POST method through `axios` like this in my React component:

```js
const submitLogout = () => {
    axios
      .post(
        "http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/logout",
      )
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  const handleClickLogOut = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();    
    submitLogout();
    props.onClose(false);
  };
```

Then I use it the following way:

```
<form onSubmit={e => handleClickLogOut(e)}>
        <button className='font-bold text-[20px]'>Log Out</button>
</form>
```

I also set the CSRF token in `axios` headers in that file:

```
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to add the CSRF token... I think you only specified the header name, not the CSRF-token itself.